# Whats is the opposite of addFieldError?

Tags: jakarta-ee, struts2, locale

I am following this [tutrial](http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-i18n-or-localization-example/) to apply locale on my application it perfectly works and show the error messages, but the difference is that the tutorial is providing a login page but I am providing a registration page.

In tutorial after an authentication a new page will be opended but I need to show a message to thanks user for their registration.

I am not sure how to use the same method as addFielderror not to show error messages, but to show confirmation of registration messages.

I used the following in my validate method but it does not work,

```
   addActionMessage(getText("confirm"));
```

my jsp

```
<s:form action="validateUser" namespace="/user">

    <s:textfield key="global.username" name="username" />
    <s:password key="global.password" name="password"/> 
    <s:submit key="global.submit" name="submit" />

</s:form>

<s:url id="localeEN" namespace="/" action="locale" >
   <s:param name="request_locale" >en</s:param>
</s:url>
<s:url id="localezhCN" namespace="/" action="locale" >
   <s:param name="request_locale" >zh_CN</s:param>
</s:url>
<s:url id="localeDE" namespace="/" action="locale" >
   <s:param name="request_locale" >de</s:param>
</s:url>
<s:url id="localeFR" namespace="/" action="locale" >
   <s:param name="request_locale" >fr</s:param>
</s:url>

<s:a href="%{localeEN}" >English</s:a>
<s:a href="%{localezhCN}" >Chinese</s:a>
<s:a href="%{localeDE}" >German</s:a>
<s:a href="%{localeFR}" >France</s:a>
```

Comment: can u show the code in jsp for action errors and action messages

Comment: @PSR question is updated

Comment: you did not specified   <s:actionmessage/> any whgere

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
<s:if test="hasActionMessages()">
   <div>
      <s:actionmessage/>
   </div>
</s:if>
```